# Can I prevent Byte Buddy from emitting default values for annotations?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

Is there any way to prevent Byte Buddy from emitting default values for annotations that I've added? Using the following the example, based on a build plugin, I'd like to see the redundant `required` and `namespace` values omitted from the resulting bytecode for the `@XmlAttribute` annotation on the `baz` field.

foo/Bar.java:

```
package foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Bar {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "qux")
    public String qux;
}
```

net/bytebuddy/test/SimplePlugin.java:

```
...    
public class SimplePlugin implements Plugin {
...    
    @Override
    public DynamicType.Builder<?> apply(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription) {
        return builder.defineField("baz", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
            .annotateField(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(XmlAttribute.class)
                .define("name", "baz")
                .build());
    }
}
```

foo/Bar.class:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Bar {
    @XmlAttribute(
        name = "qux"
    )
    public String qux;
    @XmlAttribute(
        name = "baz",
        required = false,
        namespace = "##default"
    )
    public String baz;

    public Bar() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy can be configured to skip default annotation values. However, configuring Byte Buddy is outside the scope of a transformation build plugin which implements the `Plugin` interface. The Byte Buddy API provides a separate `EntryPoint` interface which can be implemented to take control over the initialization of Byte Buddy.

net/bytebuddy/test/SimpleEntryPoint.java:

```
package net.bytebuddy.test;

...

public class SimpleEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public ByteBuddy getByteBuddy() {
        return new ByteBuddy()
            .with(AnnotationValueFilter.Default.SKIP_DEFAULTS);
    }

    ...
}
```

pom.xml:

```
...
    <plugin>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>transform</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <initialization>
                    <entryPoint>net.bytebuddy.test.SimpleEntryPoint</entryPoint>
                </initialization>
                <transformations>
                    <transformation>
                        <plugin>net.bytebuddy.test.SimplePlugin</plugin>
                    </transformation>
                </transformations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
```

foo/Bar.class:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Bar {
    @XmlAttribute(
        name = "qux"
    )
    public String qux;
    @XmlAttribute(
        name = "baz"
    )
    public String baz;

    public Bar() {
    }
}
```